# How is a class that inherits DependencyObject used?

Tags: c#, wpf

I was following a tutorial on the Dependency Object from here: http://tech.pro/tutorial/745/wpf-tutorial-introduction-to-dependency-properties

Yet, I'm still slightly confused. I created the following class which is purely for my own learning purposes and has no real usage:

```
namespace DPTest
{
    class Audio : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty fileTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("fileType", typeof(String), typeof(Audio),
        new PropertyMetadata("No File Type", fileTypeChangedCallback, fileTypeCoerceCallback), fileTypeValidationCallback);

        public String fileType
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)GetValue(fileTypeProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(fileTypeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private static void fileTypeChangedCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.OldValue + " - " + e.NewValue);
        }

        private static object fileTypeCoerceCallback(DependencyObject obj, object o)
        {
            String s = o as String;
            if (s.Length > 0)
            {
                s = s.Substring(0, 8);
            }

            return s;
        }

        private static bool fileTypeValidationCallback(object value)
        {
            return value != null;
        }
    }
}
```

A few questions:

1. Why is the property static? I don't fully understand if it's meant to store a value at the object level.
2. What does the Coerce callback do and why is it included?
3. What is the purpose of my class and where would I use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The long and short of it is you likely won't need DependencyObject's if you go [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx), but to answer your specific questions:

1. DependencyProperty *definitions* are static because all instances of the DependencyObject share the definition. They are like a [fancier per-object property Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). This also allows for various framework features to work seamlessly such as [Binding or rendering updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx#functionality).
2. [DependencyProperty Coercion occurs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events) when you need to chain together changes of properties. For example, if you had a Slider control which has a Value that should exist between a Minimum and Maximum, you use the CoerceValue callback to ensure it remains within the proper range.
3. DependencyObjects have fallen out of favor in user code, and instead are largely supplanted by the Model-View-ViewModel pattern in WPF development. Where you'll still find DependencyObjects are in custom control development. [DependencyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) are common in user code, usually in the form of [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Comment: So there's no really usage for using DependencyProperties in general desktop and mobile app development using WPF? When am I likely to need to use them?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question, which I've outlined in my answer to #3.

Answer (score 3):

The dependency property itself is static, because you are assigning the property to the object type. It identifies the property as a whole, and does not just capture the value as CLR properties do.

As you can see in the (non-static) CLR property, the storage functionality is handled by `SetValue` and `GetValue` alone. You can imagine the dependency property values as a big dictionary where you just put some arbitrary content into. The key for the dictionary is the dependency property.

The coerce callback is used to force the value into some format. In your case it will make sure that the string is only 8 characters long. Most times, you don’t need such a callback. You don’t even need a property changed callback that often. The most common case is just bindable properties and there it’s enough to just define the dependency property with standard metadata.

The purpose of your class is to serve as an example I guess. If you don’t have a specific use case, I wouldn’t advise you to even look into dependency objects. You actually very rarely subtype `DependencyObject` itself. Usually you have a framework element or component which you inherit and add custom behaviour to it. And then, whenever you need a bindable property for XAML etc., a dependency property is needed.